# XMLHttpRequest setRequestHeader Error

Tags: javascript, ajax

IE 9 developer tools say "Unspecified error." at this line of code:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("If-Modified-Since", "Sat 1 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT");
```

I am trying to disable caching of Ajax requests and I don't have control over the server and I cannot append a unique ID to the end of each request, so this looks like my only option. Any ideas why Javascript doesn't like it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was calling this before `xmlhttp.open (...);`. That was the mistake. Modify the header after you open the request, but before you send it.

```
xmlhttp.open (...);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("...", "...");
xmlhttp.send ();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have too much experience with AJAX requests, but couldn't you just call `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")` instead? Seems like that would make more sense than using the If-Modified-Since header.

Comment: Well, neither "Cache-Control" nor "If-Modified-Since" are working. I appreciate the idea though.